# iOS control Animation or Video via swiping

Tags: ios, animation, video, swipe

Is it possible to control an animation or better a video via swiping over it?

I have:

- an animation as video (~2sec playtime, can be converted to other file types if needed, but shouldn't be too big)
- iOS >= 6.0

I want:

- show the first frame of the animation
- play the animation back and forward if the user moves his finger tip over the control with a speed, corresponding to the speed of the finger tip.

[image: Video runs similar to the user interaction]

I'm experimenting with MPMoviePlayerController currently. Are there better Controls? Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: i got first successes with AVPlayer, but the performance sucks.

Comment: ok solved.... i just converted the video to an image sequence and used UIImage[50] to store them and show one of them. Sometimes the KISS solutions are the best.